# How to define an energy function, for predicting protein structure in quantum computing?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, chemistry, quantum-biology

Let q denote a particular configuration of the protein in a grid, written in the form
[image: protein configuration]

where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the $x$ and $y$ coordinate of the $i$th amino acid. For this configuration, how to define an energy function?